# Php mySQL SELECT WHERE finding only some of the entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very odd problem that is driving me crazy.
I'm trying to create a database (table) that is searchable for cryptocurrency wallet addresses.
Here's the bizarre part, the query will find some and not others.
Initially I loaded the addresses as is with mixed upper and lower case letters.
After that only finding some of the addresses I hexcoded them, same problem.
I have changed the search statements so many times now that I don't know what it's even supposed to look like.

The table is supposed to have 3 columns 1. id, 2. user hash, 3. wallet address.
I need to be able to search for a wallet address and getting the user hash returned.
I need it to be written as a function in php.
My first batch load of entries was about 20,000 rows.
IMHO it should be a very straight forward SELECT WHERE statement?

I don't even know where to begin searching for the problem?
I could give you a dozen code examples that doesn't work, I only need one that does work.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I wouldn't be asking this questing if there was a simple solution to be googled.

```
public static function get_usr($address){
    $address=bin2hex(trim($address));
    $conn = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_LOGIN, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_BASE);
    $sql = "SELECT hash FROM usr WHERE address = '$address'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "hash: " . $row["hash"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive collation?

Comment: Ok, I'll type up some non working example code. And hexcode is non case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It's the damnedest thing.
I removed the hexcoding, checked that the columns were Case-sensitive. 
Flushed the table and reloaded the data.
And now it appears to be working? I can't reproduce my own fails from earlier?
I'm happy that it now appears to be working but I didn't change anything in the code compared to what is posted above? (except for removing the bin2hex)

Answer (score -2):

The query should literally be this simple.

```
SELECT `hash`
FROM `user`
WHERE `address` = '$address' ;
```

In phpMyAdmin, if you go to the table then the structure tab, index is one of the options. I would suggest indexing the address column.

Beyond that, the only thing I can figure is that there is a problem with either the hexencoded data, or the bin2hex(trim()) call is stripping something that should be there?

The ultimate problem though has to be with the data in, or the database itself, since running the queries in phpMyAdmin doesn't work either. The first step you need to take is just working in there until you get the query to populate correctly. If you can easily re-import the data, I would empty the table and bring it back in fresh. I would suggest you set the address column type to varChar with 255, and then you shouldn't have to worry about converting the addresses.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a debugging tip.

Comment: In PhpMyAdmin: If I copy paste an entry and filter on the address it works. If I use the same address in a query, it fails. But, I'll be back with some code...

Comment: @William Perron They asked for a query that would work and I typed one that should work. How is that not an answer?

Comment: @marnell stupid question, but are you including quotation marks around the actual address in the where clause?

Comment: @marnell is the wallet address column indexed?

Comment: I added a code snippet, it works for some addresses and not for others. And I must admit I don't know if it's column indexed? I'm new to sql...